# Adding up an attribute inside entity for CoreData ios 10

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I have a tableView and that tableview is being populated with data from Coredata. The data breaks down like this.

Entity - Person

Entity - Statement
The statement entity has an attribute called amountOwed and it is of decimal type.

The relationships is that a person can have many statements, but each statement belongs to a single person.

Here is the path of the data that I would like to add up. Person > Statement > AmountOwed.

In the tableView function I have a let that represents the Person entity.

```
let person = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
```

I know its working because I can print out the persons name like so

```
print(person.name) // Bob
```

What I want to be able to do is add up all the amountOwed attributes for each Person inside the Statement entity and display them on a cell.

I have been trying to follow an example of calculated fetches but I seem to not quiet understand how to target my Statements Entities which are linked to each Person entity.

```
 let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>(entityName:"statement")
            fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType

            let sumExpressionDesc = NSExpressionDescription()
            sumExpressionDesc.name = "sumDeals"

            let specialCountExp = NSExpression(forKeyPath: #keyPath(Person.statement[indexPath].amountOwed))

            sumExpressionDesc.expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments: [specialCountExp])

            sumExpressionDesc.expressionResultsType = .interger32AttributeType

            fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [sumExpressionDesc]

            do{
                let results = try coreDataStack.managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

                let resultDict = results.first!
                let numDeals = resultDict["sumDeals"]
                print(numDeals!)
            }

            catch let error as NSError{
                print("Count not fetched \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
```

Do I need to fetch a Statement entity or should I just use the FetchedREsultsController? If I do use my fetchedResultsController does the keypath to the Statement Entity look like this

```
person[indexPath].statement.amountOwed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in one line. If the relationship from `Person` to `Statement` is called `statements`, you get the total of the amounts with

```
let amountTotal = newPerson.value(forKeyPath: "statements.@sum.amount") as? Int64
```

Change the downcast at the end from `Int64` to whatever is appropriate for your `amount` attribute-- Double or whatever.

Comment: Wow, what a great solution, so simple and clean. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

OK on your `People+CoreDataClass` add:

```
var totalOwed: Float {
    get {
        var value: Float = 0

        if let statements = self.statements.allObjects() as? [Statement] {
          for s in statements {
              value = value + s.sum
           }
        }
     return value    
}
}
```

And remove all the code from your fetch that is unnecessary